# Is there a way to put 2 databases in debug and release config and toggle between the 2 databases for debug and release mode?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

Suppose that I have this in web.config, web.debug.config and web.release.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MysqlDbContext_staging" 
         connectionString="info" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MysqlDbContext_production" 
         connectionString="info" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

public class MysqlDbContext: DbContext
{
#if DEBUG
        public static string dbName = "MysqlDbContext_staging";

#else
        public static string dbName = "MysqlDbContext_production";

#endif
        public MysqlDbContext() : base(dbName)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What I want is:

1. have some way to toggle them when I run in debug mode
2. have some way to toggle them when I run in release mode

so that I do not need to edit the database's name in the connection string every time I have to debug either of them.

Not sure if there is way to do it with Configuration Manager adding in another Debugging option when one compiles the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another config in Configuration Manager.

define a new debug macro for that config and add

```
#elif debug_production
     public static string dbName = "MysqlDbContext_production";
```